# sed: replace values in a single column

Tags: replace, sed

I want to replace a value (let's say all occurences of "25" with "Z"), like this sed command would do:

```
sed 's/25/Z/g'
```

But only in the first column of the file (so any "25" in other columns should not be replaced). Is this possible with sed, or do I need something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use `awk` for that. Having that the columns are separated by spaces the command would be as simple as:

```
awk '{sub(/25/, "Z", $1)}1' input.file
```

If the `25` can occur multiple times in the first column and you want to replace all of them use `gsub` instead of `sub`.

Comment: This seems to work, tnx! What does the "1" do after "}" ?

Comment: @Abdel An awk programs consists of one or more expression in the form `CONDITION { ACTIONS }`. Both condition and actions are optional. If no condition has been specified the actions apply to all input records. If no actions has been specified, the default action is `print` the record. The `1` takes advantage of that. It's a condition that always evaluates to `true`. Since no actions have been specified it will simply print all lines. It's the same as writing `{print}` but shorter.

Comment: That would change `1257` into `1Z7` and compress all white space in the line. Is that desirable?

Comment: @EdMorton The question is vague about that that's why I kept it simple.

Comment: In my case there were only values from 1 - 26 in that column, so hek2mgl solution was ok :)

Comment: @Abdel and you never want to replace a value less than 10? It'd fail if you tried to place 1 when 11 exists, etc. It's an extremely easy fix but you need to be clear about your requirements.

Comment: @EdMorton No, in this case I only wanted to replace the 25, so for me this was fine. But I agree with you that it is an easy fix and not suited for more complicated situations.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
echo "25 25 25 25 25" |perl -lane '$F[1]=~s/25/Z/g;print "@F"'
25 Z 25 25 25
```

Answer (score -1):

`sed` does not directly have a way to address an individual column, but you can create a regex which matches values in a particular column.

If your data is comma-separated, the regex `[^,]*` matches a field, and you can repeat as many matches of that and the separator as necessary to get to the *n*th field. So, for example,

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)25,/\1Z,/'
```

replaces `25` with `Z` in the third field.

In some more detail, the first `^` anchors the search to the beginning of line, and the parentheses capture the first two  fields into `\1` so that they can be recalled in the replacement string.

In other words, we replace the first three columns with the contents of the first two, followed by the new value for the third.

(I used commas because they are somewhat less unwieldy than spaces, and the third column to make the repeated pattern more obvious. Just a space matches itself literally, of course, or you can use `[[:space:]]` to match any one of several whitespace characters, including tab as well as some more esoteric ones. Some `sed` implementations also support the Perl synonym `\s`, but this is not standard or portable.)

Some `sed` dialects have an `-E` or `-r` option which change the regex dialect so you don't need to backslash-escape the grouping parentheses; legacy `sed` without this option supports only very basic regular expressions.

Some `sed`s also have a flag which lets you operate on the *n*th match of something, so you could say

```
sed 's/[^,]*/42/3'
```

to replace the third column with `42` everywhere.

Note also that the `g` flag in your attempt is what selected the behavior to replace all occurrences of your regular expression. The default behavior without this flag is to only replace the first match on each input line.

So, to only replace 25 in the first column, simply

```
sed 's/^25,/Z,/'
```